# Web service not accessible on host

Tags: web-services, networking, iis-7, vmware-workstation

Folks, I published a web service on iis7 on a remote win on vm ware and I can't acess it on the host os, even though I set up Nat port forwarding on vm ware and opened the corresponding port on the host`s firewall settings.

My web service ip on guest is http://localhost:80/webservice.asmx

Even when I try the same address with 9997 port on the host it won't work after opening port 9997 on firewall and setup a port forward on Virtual network editor on vmnet8 (NAT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, 
 I just needed to disable firewall on Guest both Home and Public Networks.